# JQuery datepicker only works if I put an alert() in the script

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm coding a jQuery datatable with some input fields (on each row). One of the fields needs to be a date and so I'm trying to use jQuery datepicker to accomplish the input for that field.

The field in question is rendered for each row using a template:

```
var invoiceDateInputTemplate = '<input class="datepicker" id="InvoiceDate_{0}" name="InvoiceDate_{0}" type="text" />';
```

During the datatable build, I render the template and replace the {0} with the appropriate Id so the id & name parameters are unique for each row.

At the end of my $(document).ready() function, after the table has been built, I run the following code to make each of my 'date' fields into a datepicker enabled field using the class selection option. For some reason, this doesn't seem to want to cause the fields to become datepicker enabled:

```
$(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

If I add an alert() call prior to the $(".datepicker").datepicker(), it works like a champ... an alert() call after the datepicker initialization does NOT work.

This causes the DatePicker to render:

```
$(function() {
    alert();
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

This causes the DatePicker to NOT render (included to provide an example):

```
$(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    alert();
});
```

Why is this happening? Am I missing something that would be causing the DatePicker to not initialize the fields as expected? I'm pretty sure that it isn't standard operating procedure to have to fire an alert to get DatePicker to work correctly. Also, just to clarify, I don't believe that I have any fields being focused upon after the datatable builds.

Comment: Is `.datepicker` definately rendered before the js runs? Try wrapping it in a `setTimeout(function () {$(".datepicker").datepicker();}, 500)`

Comment: you should just add a document ready

Comment: You should just [edit] your question to include a [mcve] so it can be on-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, @Guy had the solution... I set the function up within a setTimeout and it started working as it should:

```
setTimeout(function() {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    },1000);
```

I should have thought of that earlier... Thanks @Guy!

Answer (score 2):

I get the feeling that you've got an async problem!

The easiest solution is to bind the call to `datepicker()` on a custom event, then trigger the event after the datatable is built. Like so:

```
$(function() {
    // Create data table here
    $(window).trigger('datatable.built');
});

$(window).on('datatable.built', function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for datatable? Most probably it renders after you attach event, in that case it should have an event like draw or somethingwhich indicates that data is rendered

Comment: yeah my bad, forgot that

Answer (score 0):

Try use this:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("focusin",".datepicker",function(){
        $(this).datepicker();
    });
});
```

if it works, you can improve for not "recreate" datepicker everytime the element get focus